# To display department ID using department name in python with psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

With psycopg2 in python, I'm trying to retrieve department ID using department name for new employee details by inserting as raw query. But, I couldn't able to find any solution for this problem. Is there any solution for this problem which will help me to complete my task?

This is my employee database:
[image]

This is my python code:

```
import datetime

import psycopg2.extras
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="emp", user="postgres",
                        password="12345", host="127.0.0.1", 
port="5432")

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)

emp_name = str(input("Enter new employee name: "))

while True:
    gender = str(input("Type your gender: "))
    if gender == 'M' or gender == 'F':
        break

hire_date = input("Enter hire date(YYYY-MM-DD): ")
year, month, day = map(int, hire_date.split('-'))
hiredate = datetime.date(year, month, day)

salary = str(int(input("Enter your salary: ")))

deptname = str(input("Enter department name: "))

cur.execute("INSERT INTO employee(emp_name, gender, hire_date, salary,
 deptid) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)",(emp_name, gender,hire_date, salary))

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY emp_no DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE 
  deptname = %(deptname)s", {'deptname': deptname})

rows = cur.fetchall()

print( '\n'.join( str( row ) for row in rows ) )

print( "Created successfully!" )
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: I don't see `deptname` field in the insert query, how do you want to retrieve something that isn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display department ID using department name can be achieved by this following query:

```
deptname = str(input("Enter department name: "))

cur.execute("SELECT deptid FROM department WHERE department.deptname = %("
            "deptname)s", {'deptname': deptname})
deptid = cur.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only deptid, Use this.

```
 cur.execute('''SELECT d.deptid FROM department d 
        WHERE d.deptname =  %(deptname)s''', {'deptname': deptname})
```

If you want the details of all employees in that department

```
 cur.execute('''SELECT e.* FROM employee e JOIN department d 
               ON  d.deptid = e.deptid 
        WHERE d.deptname =  %(deptname)s''', {'deptname': deptname})
```

Comment: Getting error like this: `psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "deptid" violates not-null constraint`